# Cursor moving erratically on its own (not a duplicated)

Tags: ubuntu, xinput

I've read [this post that is very similar to mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328538/cursor-moving-erratically-on-its-own), but the difference is that I have the touchpad disabled and my xinput show as if I have more than one mouse installed when I only have just one wireless Genius mouse since a long time.

I have an Asus K501U, intel core i7, nvidia Geforce 940MX, with 12GB of RAM and SSD drive of 512 GB. I'm using Ubuntu Focal Fossa. It's the development brunch (I tried to install the latest stable version, but by mistake I installed this one). Anyway, the Ubuntu installation occurred about a year ago, and I've installed the latest security updates since then.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Genius Wireless Device                    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Genius Wireless Device Consumer Control   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Genius Wireless Device System Control     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Genius Wireless Device                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V           id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Genius Wireless Device Consumer Control   id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

If I try `xinput disable 16`, and `xinput disable 13`, and nothing happens... I try `xinput` again after that and the list remains exactly the same.

What can I do??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to copy/paste in a pretty way, because it looks terrible when I just paste what's on the terminal.

Comment: Looks just perfect. Silly me. Thanks @Eduardo!

Comment: When you run `xinput disable 16` nothing should happen besides your touchpad being disabled. If you want to look if the device is actually disabled you can do for example `xinput --list-props 16` and you should see a line near the top `Enabled` with the value `1` or `0`. With the device 16 disabled, do you still experience the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I will post how did I solved the issue. Because it's so silly that I cant believe it.

Just in case it happens to you, and you start thinking about all sort of things, whereas sometimes, you need to start with a simple idea first: The batteries of the mouse were almost gone.

Yes, changing the batteries solved the problem. I tried using it for a while, in order to be sure. But it did.